# PowerShell to delete versioning

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to delet all the versions of a list item that do not have comments in a field called OverallComments, everything works up to deleting the version(s)

```
$site = Get-SPWeb -Identity "[mysite]/bussupport/businessit/"
$list = $site.lists["Account Tracker"]
$currentVersionsCount = 0
$countDeleted = 0
$i = 0 

#Loop through all items in the WCP list
foreach ($listItem in $list.Items)
{
    #Delete all version history where the OverallComments are null.
    if ($listItem["ID"] -eq "73")
    {
        $currentVersionsCount = $listItem.Versions.Count
        write-host "Number of versions: " $currentVersionsCount 

            foreach ($item in $listItem.Versions)
            {        

                if ($item["OverallComments"] -eq $null)
                {
                    $listItem.versions[$item.VersionLabel].delete();
                    $countDeleted++
                }
            }
    write-host "Number of deleted versions: " $countDeleted 
    }
}
$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, $listItem.versions[$item.VersionLabel].delete(); returns an error, "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

Comment: Shouldn't you use $item.delete() instead of $listItem.versions[$item.VersionLabel].delete();

Comment: UBK - I had tried that as well.  It would delet the first version it came accorss then error after that.  See Lee_MSFT's answer below, this was what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below script

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$site = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://site/"
$list = $site.lists["VersionList"]
$currentVersionsCount = 0
$countDeleted = 0
$i = 0 

#Loop through all items in the WCP list
foreach ($listItem in $list.Items)
{
    #Delete all version history where the OverallComments are null.
    if ($listItem["ID"] -eq "1")
    {
        $currentVersionsCount = $listItem.Versions.Count
        write-host "Number of versions: " $currentVersionsCount 
        $versionToDelete = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
        foreach ($item in $listItem.Versions)
        {        
            if ($item["Option"] -ne $null)
            {
                #$listItem.versions[$item.VersionLabel].delete();
                $versionToDelete.Add($item)                
            }
        }
        for($i=$versionToDelete.Count-1;$i -ge 0;$i--){
            if($versionToDelete[$i].IsCurrentVersion -ne $true){
                $versionToDelete[$i].delete()
                $countDeleted++;
            }
        }
        write-host "Number of deleted versions: " $countDeleted 
    }
}
$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you Lee_MSFT, this worked perfectly!